# Using different config and content database servers

Tags: 2007, content-database, farm, config-database

Here's the situation. I have two farms PROD and DR. One of the scenario is to point DR farm to PROD database.

So basically SharePoint servers will be DR ones but database will be PROD one.

Is it possible? Because hostnames of both DR and PROD are different so I am thinking this will not work (as config database of PROD and DR is different) plus some shared service providers are working on PROD but not on DR.

But I see there is a connection string saved in registry of SharePoint server which points to Config database. So I was thinking to point this registry database to DR and then use alias (cliconfg) to point to content database on PROD. I am not sure if it is workable or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would indicate your DR is within close proximity to your production (less than ~186 miles) with a 1Gbps or greater link between the DR site and the PROD site as SharePoint requires 1Gbps/<=1ms connectivity to the SQL Server(s).

You can do this. You create a new DR farm which has it's own Admin/Config db, then you can mount the content databases in a read-only state. Of course if your PROD SQL Server goes down, there's little point in this configuration which offers near zero business value. Instead, look into replicating the SQL databases from PROD to a DR SQL Server using Mirroring, AlwaysOn, or Log Shipping. You would then attached those databases on the DR SQL Server in a read-only state on the DR farm.

[Choose a disaster recovery strategy for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628971.aspx)

Comment: This is how I did it originally. I created a new DR farm with new config DB. Then I backed up content db on prod and restored it on DR SQL Server. Then I attached that content database to DR web application.

Now what if I want to keep using DR config database but content database should be read from PROD?

Comment: So you're not running DR, then. You're simply using two farms on the same SQL Server, one with read-only. DR implies that the setup is not only using separate farms, but geographically separated as well. You're going to use the same SQL Server, thus have no DR as all of your databases will go down if that SQL Server fails. You should instead be using a form of SQL replication to replicate to the DR SQL Server and mount the Content Databases as read-only from the DR farm against the DR SQL Server.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. DR and PROD are both geographically separated and two different farms.

DR connects to DRSQL while PROD connects to PRODSQL. To update content db, we take back up from PRODSQL and restore it on DRSQL (currently this process is manual but we will use mirroring/replication in future)

Comment: That will be the way you need to do it, then. You cannot connect DRFARM to PRODSQL due to the distance/line speed (likely <1Gbps).